# Read Firebase Database without any form of authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Is there a any way that I can read the data in firebase node without any kind of authentication?

I'm writing an android/ios app where new users should have valid invitation code. So to do that I have to check user has valid invitation code before let them create the account. I have saved all the valid invitation codes in one node. I want to validate the user entered code against the codes in that list.

Currently I have allowed both read and write to my database.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

I'm not getting any kind of response from `addValueEventListener` or `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use anonymous auth, else post your code to understand it better.

Comment: with those database rules, you dont have to authenticate

Comment: @PeterHaddadI tried but no response from the Firebase. Not even an error.

Answer (score 2):

If u make read and write rules, as true, it can be read by anyone. So there is no security. Its better you authenticate the user by "Firebase Anonymous Authentication" and then read from database. In anonymous auth , the user will be authenticated in background, they dont have to do anything.
In that way , you will not compromise security.
This is the tutorial for using anonymous auth in firebase [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth)

```
mAuth.signInAnonymously()
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:success");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                updateUI(user);
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "signInAnonymously:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(AnonymousAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: signInAnonymously is creating a new user. That can not be happen as the user might already have a account.

Comment: You can convert anonymous signin into permanent. 
 check this doc - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth?authuser=0#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account

Answer (score 0):

Structure your schema to have a node dedicated to un-authenticated access and then do something like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "invitations": {
            ".read": "true",
            ".write": "false"
        },
        "$other_locations": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null"
        }
    }
}
```

Comes down to your use case really.